# Any nice way to generate a timeline view of commits from subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, trac

Just starting out with subversion, have set up repos for 3 current projects and all seems good. Subclipse is nice isn't it!

Anyway, what I'd like to have is a nice timeline showing the commits with comments for these repos. They are all hosted on the same server as the websites that they contain.

I've tried trac, which does what I want, but seems a huge overkill as I don't really want the tickets/wiki/etc, just the timeline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclipse plugin for eclipse can create a timeline showing revisions, branches, merges, etc.
There are probably others as well, though.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/

edit: yup, TortoiseSVN also does this. see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html

Edit 2: To be fair, neither of the above create timelines per se. They both create revision graphs. The date/time of the commits are available in subclipse (and probably tortoisesvn as well) by hovering over the elements of the graph, (and looking at the revision history table) but strictly speaking they aren't timelines. I'm not aware of anything that produces this information in a timeline format. Hopefully those meet your needs.

Comment: The subclipse history table is fine for now - how do you get the revision graph?

Comment: from within eclipse, right-click the file/folder you want info on, go to the Team submenu, and click on view file history as graph. It can take a little while to generate the graph -- especially for more complex svn histories

Answer (score 0):

Use the `svn log` command.  Add a `-v` flag to show what files were modified by each commit.  The output is likely to be voluminous, so you will probably want to limit the output to the last 100 or so lines using the `-l` flag.  Putting it all together:

1. Start a command prompt such as `bash` on Linux or `cmd.exe` on Windows.
2. `cd` *your repository*
3. `svn log -l 100 -v`