# Which SVN client can do a full repository timeline visualization?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, visualization

I want to do code archeology to get an overview on how 20+ long-living branches in a subversion repository relate to each other.

I think the best visualization would be a horizontal timeline with all branches in parallel with activity markers for the commits and indications for merges. I yet have to find a tool that makes this possible. Importing into Git and using gitk is the best solution so far, but the branch indicators in gitk run vertically and are not normalized for the time axis, which makes it really hard to see if branches were active at the same time.

Does anyone know a solution that's readable with a long history 3 years, 50,000 commits, 20+ branches?

Thanks in advance!
Florian

I'd like the following:

```
Dec 1           Dec 10         Dec 20
-----------------------------------------
trunk      *        *           *    *
            \                  /
branch1       *    *       *  *         *

* = commits
/\ = merges
```

Tools I tried so far:
IntelliJ Revision Graph (looks like what I imagined but zooming does not work)
Tortoise (visualizes vertically and cannot normalize on time scale)
Versions (Mac)
gitk / GitX

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929842/any-nice-way-to-generate-a-timeline-view-of-commits-from-subversion

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your repository with git-svn, then gitk.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I first tried. gitk is ok, but I want a real timeline like visualization (with equidistant time units). And horizontal.